# Can't divide two ints

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to get the break point conversion by dividing two ints. dVariables is the name I gave to my global variable.

```
int totalBreakPoints = dVariables.gBreakPointsWon1 + dVariables.gBreakPointsWon2;
int breakCon1 = dVariables.gBreakPointsWon1 / totalBreakPoints;
NSLog(@"%d", breakCon1);
```

But whenever I run this, the code crashes and displays this: "Thread 1: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code = EXC_1386_DIV, subcode 0 * 0). Is there any reason why this may be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a divide-by-zero exception.  You need to check whether `totalBreakPoints` is zero before doing this.